# Prove $\sum_k{2k\choose k}^2{2\left(n-k\right)\choose n-k}^2=\sum_k(-1)^k16^k{n-k \choose k}{2\left(n-k\right)\choose n-k}^3$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, summation

So I've come across this one :

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\left[{2k\choose k}{2\left(n-k\right)\choose n-k}\right]^2=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right\rfloor}\left(-1\right)^k16^k{n-k \choose k}{2\left(n-k\right)\choose n-k}^3$$
It looks nice, but since I am not really familiar with combinatorics, I have no clue as how to prove it.

What would you suggest ?

Answer (score 3):

Not  an answer  but too  long for  a comment.  The Maple  **sumtools**
package features an implementation of Zeilberger's algorithm, exported
through  the  **sumrecursion** command.  This  will  produce the  same
recurrence for the LHS and the RHS. Then we just need to check the two
initial values. This is the Maple transcript.

```
> with(sumtools);
[Hypersum, Sumtohyper, extended_gosper, gosper, hyperrecursion, hypersum,

    hyperterm, simpcomb, sumrecursion, sumtohyper]

> sumrecursion(binomial(2*k,k)^2*binomial(2*n-2*k,n-k)^2, k,S(n));
              3                             2                             3
   256 (n - 1)  S(-2 + n) - 8 (2 n - 1) (2 n  - 2 n + 1) S(n - 1) + S(n) n

> sumrecursion((-1)^k*16^k*binomial(n-k,k)*binomial(2*n-2*k,n-k)^3, k, S(n));
              3                             2                             3
   256 (n - 1)  S(-2 + n) - 8 (2 n - 1) (2 n  - 2 n + 1) S(n - 1) + S(n) n

> A := n -> add(binomial(2*k,k)^2*binomial(2*n-2*k,n-k)^2, k=0..n);
                                 2                           2
   A := n -> add(binomial(2 k, k)  binomial(2 n - 2 k, n - k) , k = 0 .. n)

> seq(A(n), n=1..5);
                          8, 88, 1088, 14296, 195008

> B := n -> add((-1)^k*16^k*binomial(n-k,k)*binomial(2*n-2*k,n-k)^3, k=0..n);
B := n ->

            k   k                                              3
    add((-1)  16  binomial(n - k, k) binomial(2 n - 2 k, n - k) , k = 0 .. n)

> seq(B(n), n=1..5);
                          8, 88, 1088, 14296, 195008
```

The common recurrence is

$$256\, \left( n-1 \right) ^{3}S \left( n-2 \right) -8\, \left( 2\,n-1
 \right)  \left( 2\,{n}^{2}-2\,n+1 \right) S \left( n-1 \right) +S
 \left( n \right) {n}^{3} = 0.$$

This  is a  classic example  from the  foreword to  the book  *A=B* by
Petkovsek,  Wilf, and  Zeilberger,  and identified  as  such at  [OEIS
A036917](https://oeis.org/A036917).

Comment: I think this is an answer! It gives an inductive proof of the equation.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Should not  the recurrence formula be proven in an uderstandable way?